# How to manually trigger Paypal error 10486 in sandbox?

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

Paypal says, use CCREJECT-REFUSED for address1 in credit card detail. https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec_fundingfailure10486/

I tried creating new test user (CC credential was automatically created). Login into sandbox and add CC detail I got from first step. I change address line to CCREJECT-REFUSED. Save it. And then tested it, checking out via sandbox. Error 10486 was not triggered.

Any hint?

Answer (score 7):

Mistake I made was to edit the SHIPPING address instead of the BILLING address.

Your best bet is to log directly into https://www.sandbox.paypal.com  and hit the 'Profile' tab and try to add or edit a card there.

Watch out for the following :

- Make sure you put exactly `CCREJECT-REFUSED` for **BILLING** address Line 1 with no spaces and TWO `C` at the beginning
- They seem to be incompetent to keep the site running smoothly at all times so just try again 
  later if you get `Service Temporarily Unavailable`.
- Make sure if you're adding a new card (you can use your own real card number) that you aren't getting a message telling you `This card number is already assigned to another PayPal account. For security reasons, each card may only be assigned to one PayPal account` because then you'll not be adding anything
- Make sure payment method is actually set to credit card before you hit Submit for the order.

It does actually work though (as of today)

Comment: Now I can't get it to work since they don't let me choose the payment source at checkout... :-/

Comment: Needed to do this again and it still works. Just add a card with CCREJECT-REFUSED for billing and it will trigger this error. SANDBOX ONLY though. There's no negative testing in production.

Answer (score 4):

All of these answers are now out of date. It's impossible to add a card with `CCREJECT-REFUSED` as the address and, if you could, it wouldn't do anything. You should follow the instructions at: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_error-conditions/

For the majority of APIs exposed by PayPal, this usually involves setting the order amount to the desired error code *after* enabling negative testing mode for your sandbox business account.

For example, triggering a `10486` via the Express Checkout NVP API would involve setting the `AMT` to $104.86.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I was wrong to assume that the error can be triggered using direct CC payment.

As the document suggest:

1. You need to create a test user account
2. Login into sandbox using fore-mentioned account.
3. Change address part of test user CC to: `CCREJECT-REFUSED`

Then, in order to test it, run your express checkout flow as usual. But on the last part, **do not use direct CC input**. Instead, choose the other option -- **login into your test user paypal account**.

You will then received this kind of response:

`TIMESTAMP=2013%2d08%2d19T06%3a50%3a45Z&CORRELATIONID=6761aff7944b&ACK=Failure&VERSION=104&BUILD=7319395&L_ERRORCODE0=10486&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=This%20transaction%20couldn%27t%20be%20completed%2e&L_LONGMESSAGE0=This%20transaction%20couldn%27t%20be%20completed%2e%20Please%20redirect%20your%20customer%20to%20PayPal%2e&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error`

Comment: I should add one more detail. When PayPal test user is created it has bank account as default payment method. During purchase for non-recurring payment there is "Payment methods" section. I changed there bank to credit card. And than I was able to get this error. Also note that PayPal than may change payment method bank again after payment fail.

Answer (score 1):

As taking directly from [their](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec_fundingfailure10486/) [tutorial](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec_fundingfailure10486/): (see step 2)

1. Login to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com using your buyer's test PayPal account.
2. **Replace the contents of the *street address Line-1* of the buyer's test credit card, with <kbd>CCREJECT-REFUSED</kbd>**.
3. Execute a typical Express Checkout payment flow against the Sandbox test environment using the same buyer account and with the same credit card that you just modified.
4. When you execute <kbd>DoExpressCheckoutPayment</kbd>, error code <kbd>10486</kbd> will be returned. Your code should redirect the buyer back to PayPal using the same redirect URL used to start the checkout flow and the same Express Checkout token.

Comment: Before you posted this answer, did you tried to do these steps? Paypal Sandbox returns error in case when you try to execute step 2 from your answer.

Comment: @mrDinkelman I had at the time, but that was 3 years ago! Paypal changes like every month!