# Pay-Pal error code 10486

Tags: paypal-sandbox

Can anyone manage to follow the steps to reproduce this error code found in the paypal dev document https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec_fundingfailure10486/

I'm unable complete this step

2. Replace the contents of the street address Line-1 of the buyer's test credit card, with CCREJECT-REFUSED.

When I attempt to save the card from the sandbox I get this error:
This card is not accepted. Please use a different card.

I've also attempted to change the address at the time of checkout which seems to save but then does not result in the required error code which i need for my testing.

If you can follow the steps from the tutorial please let me know.

(also this issue is similar but different from [How to manually trigger Paypal error 10486 in sandbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18275583/how-to-manually-trigger-paypal-error-10486-in-sandbox). The difference is that I'm not able to edit the address to the CCREJECT-REFUSED)

Thanks

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you manage to find a way to edit line 1 billing card to CCREJECT-REFUSED?

Comment: Confirmed. PayPal sandbox is not allow to save billing address in case when CCREJECT-REFUSED selected as street line 1 (like in docs). Facepalm.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to PayPal credit:

- Place an order for ~600 USD
- Start an express checkout session
- Select PayPal credit as funding source
- Attempt to process the order

Generally, PayPal Credit will give you a credit limit of like $587-ish. Placing an order above this credit limit and attempting to place an order should generate the 10486 error. At that point you should be able to call setExpressCheckout again to recover the transaction by selecting another funding source.

Comment: PayPal credit should be available for USA and perhaps GBR.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal announce new way for emulate negative behaviours.

Please take a look - https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_error-conditions/

You can emulate negative scenarios and now don't need to make dances with extra-tuning for customer accounts and etc.

**REST**: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/nt-rest/

If you're like old school games and other dances around, try SOAP: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/nt-classic/

Note: This feature working only for **Sandbox** Instanse.